# Template tag for conditionally rendering or including another template if the path or paths exist

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I am implementing a generic dropdown menu within a Django application. In most cases, the pages are generic and they have simple generic 'children' menus. However in some cases, I want to be able to include or render a special set of children, or custom content from a completely different template, based upon the page slug (page.slug).

I have considered implementing an inclusion tag but I am not sure about how to do this in a template tag. I know in views you can implement it like so:

```
blog_post = get_object_or_404(blog_posts, slug=slug)
...
templates = [u"blog/blog_post_detail_%s.html" % str(slug), template]
return render(request, templates, context)
```

My design pattern for the tag would be simple:

1. Look within pages/SLUG/dropdown.html
2. Try pages/dropdown_SLUG.html
3. Render nothing if none of those files exist.

How can I do this from a template tag? Is an inclusion tag the right way, or a render_tag?

Comment: So are you saying if their is a special set of children display it in the drop down menu, if not display a generic drop down menu.

Comment: No, basically I want to render a special template/include it from the dropdown menu template if the path exists, for instance to render a custom menu for an area of the site that might have additional content that isn't just a tree of page links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
@register.render_tag
def page_menu_special(context, token):
    page = None
    template_name = None
    menu_templates = []

    parts = token.split_contents()[1:]
    for part in parts:
        part = Variable(part).resolve(context)
        if isinstance(part, str):
            template_name = part
        elif isinstance(part, Page) or isinstance(part, CustomPage):
            page = part

    if page and page.slug:
        page_template = str(page.slug) if page.slug != home_slug() else "index"
        method_template = page.get_content_model().get_template_name()

        menu_templates.extend([
            u'pages/menus/dropdown_%s.html' % (page_template),
            u'pages/menus/dropdown/%s.html' % (page_template),
        ])

        if method_template:
            menu_templates.append(method_template)

    if template_name:
        menu_templates.insert(0, template_name)

    try:
        t = select_template(menu_templates)
        return t.render(Context(context))
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        return u''
```

It is rather specific to Mezzanine, but the logic can be reused:

1. Build paths to potential templates.
2. Pass the list to select_template
3. Catch exception if none exist, and return empty or suitable rendered content.

I'm still trying to figure out how to default to **another** template tag, from **within** this definition. So I can call `page_menu_special` and if this one fails, it reverts back to a call to `page_menu` with the same arguments and that saves us an `if/else` block.